# How to make the carousel buttons responsive? Nothing I found has helped yet

Tags: carousel

I have literally looked up everything and tried everything i found. First off all, there is a white space showing between the pictures, second, I can't click on the buttons to go to the next image, what do I do wrong?

I think I am doing something wrong with the head. I have tried copying multiple tutorials, and everything from the bootstrap website, still the results are different then. Also when working on my Navbar the results are different, so I feel like it might be more of a underlying problem?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>A</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>


<!--image caroussle-->


<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" 
data-interval="2000">
    
  

<!--Carousel content-->
    <div class="carousel-inner"  >
        
    
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="/Kant en klaar/Carousel/Sfeer 1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Responsive image" alt="first slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="/Kant en klaar/Carousel/_MG_9087.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Responsive image" alt="second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="/Kant en klaar/Carousel/_MG_9352.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Responsive image" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        
    </div>
    

    <!--End Carousel content-->


    <!-- Previous & Next Buttons-->
    <a href="#Carousel" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="#Carousel" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>

</div>
    <!--end image catousel-->



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```